# Animation Nodes - Clear all caches at once?

Tags: animation-nodes

I find myself using caches in AN subprograms a lot lately. However, if I want to clear the caches, I need to walk through the various nodes and click "clear cache" individually.  This can get tedious on complex node trees.

Is there any built-in way to reset / clear all the subprogram caches at once?

I did not see any mention in docs nor tutorials I've seen.

Comment: I don't think it is possible at the moment. Anyway, feel free to open an issue on Github as a feature request, see what Jacques has to say about it.

Comment: Done.  https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1063